# Node/react how to return pure html rendered with react and send to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, render-to-string

I have a simple node.js app that should be responding to requests with pure HTML using React's `renderToString` function. The code for rendering and responding looks like this:

```
const markup = renderToString(
    <Provider {...stores}>
        <Router location={req.url} context={{}} history={browserHistory}>
            <Routes/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

res.status(200).send(markup);
```

And the HTML response:

```
<section data-reactroot="">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div>Body</div>
</section>
```

I don't want any trace of react in the output. Is there a way, when rendering with react, to not include the `data-reactroot` or any other traces of react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `renderToStaticMarkup` instead of `renderToString` and there wont be any trace of react in the output (reference https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React 16? Once you are using that version, [none of the generated React attributes should be present](https://hackernoon.com/whats-new-with-server-side-rendering-in-react-16-9b0d78585d67).